# jQuery, else if isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm sending data to my database using .ajax. I've got two fields. I'd like to check if either are empty and if so display an error. The first if works fine. That message display, but the else if doesn't display. What could be my problem? I'm not too familiar with javascript and iquery.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
     beforeSend: function() {
        if (!$.trim($("#cat").val())) {
            $(".fb-error").css( "display", "block" );
            $(".fb-error").html("<p>the cat field is empty</p>");
            xhr.abort();
        }

        else if (!$.trim($("#box").val())) {
            $(".fb-error").css( "display", "block" );
            $(".fb-error").html("<p>the box field is empty</p>");
            xhr.abort();
        }
    },
    success: function(html){
        $('textarea#box').val('');
        $("#box-wrap").prepend(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: Delete the space between { and else if ?

Comment: If you want the two messages to be displayed at the same time, you should not use *`else`* `if`, and you should append the messages to the element instead of overwriting them.

Comment: @Mark, since when is whitespace significant in Javascript?

Comment: Doesn't help anything.

Comment: @Frederic, but I want to run both checks and have two different messages depending on the error so what do you suggest?

Comment: Do you want both messages to be displayed at the same time if both fields are empty?

Comment: I want both messages to display at once, but I want to check both separately and produce two different error messages depending on the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `else` if you want to check both conditions.

```
var error = '';

if (!$.trim($("#cat").val())) {
        error = "<p>the cat field is empty</p>";
}

if (!$.trim($("#box").val())) {
        error += "<p>the box field is empty</p>";
}

if (error) {
        $(".fb-error").html(error);
        $(".fb-error").css( "display", "block" );
        xhr.abort();
}
```

In second `if` you have to append new html, to prevent overwriting already added message.

Comment: I'd personally switch from `html()` to `$(".fb-error").append("<p>MESSAGE</p>");` for each of the validated fields

Comment: Thank you! I really like this method.

Comment: You could even go overboard and store the validations in an array: `var validations = [{selector: '#cat', message: 'the cat field is empty'}, {selector: '#box', message: 'the box field is empty'}];
for (var k in validations) if (!$.trim(validations[key].selector).val()) // etc...`

Comment: It would end up as more code though. [http://jsfiddle.net/hyk9N/](http://jsfiddle.net/hyk9N/)

Answer (score 2):

Use separate `if` statements for each condition; `else if` only runs if the first `if` fails. Use a variable to accumulate the messages.

```
 beforeSend: function() {
    var msg = '';
    if (!$.trim($("#cat").val())) {
        $(".fb-error").css( "display", "block" );
        msg = "<p>the cat field is empty</p>";
        xhr.abort();
    }
    if (!$.trim($("#box").val())) {
        $(".fb-error").css( "display", "block" );
        msg += "<p>the box field is empty</p>";
        xhr.abort();
    }
    $(".fb-error").html(msg);
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd put the errors in an array, and display them if it's not empty

```
var errors = [];
if (!$.trim($("#cat").val())) {
    errors.push("<p>the cat field is empty</p>");
}

if (!$.trim($("#box").val())) {
    errors.push("<p>the box field is empty</p>");
}

if(errors.length){
    $(".fb-error").css( "display", "block" ).html(errors.join(''));
    xhr.abort();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consolidate:

```
var error = false;
if (!$.trim($("#cat").val())) {
        $(".fb-error").append("<p>the cat field is empty</p>");
        error = true;
}

if (!$.trim($("#box").val())) {
        $(".fb-error").append("<p>the box field is empty</p>");
        error = true;
}

if (error) {
        xhr.abort();
        $(".fb-error").css( "display", "block" );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To debug can you switch around #box and #cat?

You are using an else, so if #cat is empty, you will not see the message "the box field is empty". It will only show this message if #cat is not empty, and #box is.

change #box to something you know doesn't exist (and cannot exist). perhaps there is a value in it.

you could ouput the value of #cat and #box to the console to ensure that they are empty.

console.log("$.trim($("#cat").val()="+$.trim($("#cat").val());
console.log("$.trim($("#box").val()="+$.trim($("#box").val());

Comment: I can't figure out what you're telling him to do to fix the code.